# Which Nuget Unity packages for ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: c#, unity-container, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC5 project that relies on Unity (IoC) for DI. The other day I started watching the Pluralsight course "Practical IoC with ASP.NET MVC 4" and the guy doing that course chooses the Unity for MVC 4 package over the Unity package (talking Nuget packages here) where obviously you setup everything in a file called Bootstrapper.cs, which, as I understand it, is created and wired up by that Nuget package.

My project doesn't have this file, but actually references Unity.Mvc4 (the one that's recommended in the course). The Nuget package manager tells me that Unity.MVC4 and Unity are both installed and that Unity.MVC4 depends on Unity.

To make matters worse, there also is Unity.MVC5 and Unity bootstrapper for ASP.NET MVC available from nuget.org. Is it just me, or is that a tiny bit confusing?

Can anybody please shed some light on which Unity packages actually make sense with MVC 5?

Comment: Bootstrapper is hooked into the application start event among others, you can also use the Application_Start event in global.asax. Has MVC a global.asax :-) Don't think so.  In the bootstrapper you do create the Unity container and do the mappings. So you need Unity always, but it gets installed with one of the packages u mentioned above like Unity.MVC.Just delete the Unity.MVC reference and delete the references in the packages file and rebuild the project, then it will install it again and create the bootstrapper file four you automatically. But if u use MVC5 I would recommend Unity.MVC5

Comment: Yes, MVC has a global.asax. From there I call into Startup.InitialiseUnityContainer, which works perfectly fine. I removed the MVC4 package and the installed the MVC5 one, can't tell the difference, but there still is no Bootstrapper.cs file as far as I can see. Guess they changed that for MVC5.

Comment: This is completely ok. Bootstrapper is just an .cs/.vb/etc. file where u put your bootstrap stuff inside in one place and which is is hooked into the event pipline using WebActivatorEx. So calling it form app_start in global.asax is also fine.

Answer (score 1):

This won't help anyone using MVC 5, but ASP.NET Core has own DI implementation, take a look: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/06/17/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-vnext.aspx and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection

Believe that native feature would be better than side implementation of this pattern.

Comment: It's not quite clear from the article which version of ASP.NET MVC will have support for this out of the box DI (they only refer to ASP.NET vNext). Besides, I prefer choosing the container I'm already familiar with and haven't had any issues using the extension points that already exist in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: This article refers to ASP.Net vNext, which was called ASP.Net 5, which is not the same as MVC 5.